# Getting generic type of super interface via reflection

Tags: java, reflection

```
interface BaseDao<T> { }

interface UserDao extends BaseDao<User> { }

interface DeptDao extends BaseDao<Department> { }
```

I need a function get `Entity` class via `Dao` class, like this:

```
func(UserDao.class) return User.class
func(DeptDao.class) return Deparment.class
```

and I **don't** like add `annotation` to`dao`, like this:

```
@Entity(User.class)
interface UserDao extends BaseDao
```

### ---------------------------------------------------------

inspired by dimo414 's suggestion, this is my solution:

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // if A and B are Class, then it be 'B.class.getGenericSuperclass()'
    Type genType = B.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0];

    if (genType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        Type[] params = ((ParameterizedType) genType).getActualTypeArguments();
        Class<?> clz = (Class) params[0];
        System.out.println(clz); // class java.lang.String
    }
}}

interface A<T> {}

interface B extends A<String> {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Guava's [`TypeToken`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html), which does what (I think) you're describing. More details in their [Reflection Explained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained) article.

The [`TypeCapture.capture()`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/reflect/TypeCapture.java) method gets the generic type of the parent class:

```
Type capture() {
  Type superclass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
  checkArgument(superclass instanceof ParameterizedType, "%s isn't parameterized", superclass);
  return ((ParameterizedType) superclass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

and that's how `TypeToken`'s "magic" works.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make the class available in your code is to expose a method on your BaseDao

```
Class<T> getClassType();
```

then in your implementation you pass the class type in the constructor e.g.

```
public class AbstractDao<T> implements BaseDao<T> {

    private Class<T> clasType;

    public AbstractDao(Class<T> clasType) {
        this.clasType = clasType;
    }

    public Class<T> getClassType() {
        return clasType;
    }
}


public class UserDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<User> implements UserDao     {

    public UserDaoImpl() {
        super(User.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserDaoImpl dao = new UserDaoImpl();
        System.out.print(dao.getClassType());
    }
}
```

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime) for more discussion